# Terraform complex object validation

Tags: terraform

I have a complex object that looks like this:

```
  type = map(object({
    priority                   = number
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
    }
```

I want a validation rule that checks if `access == "Allow"` and `source_address_prefix = "*"`

However I can't make this work.

Here are my example inputs:

```
network_acls = {
  "allowTrafficOfficeIP" = {
    priority                   = 1
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "8.8.8.8"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  "blockInbound" = {
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Deny"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  "blockOutbound" = {
    priority                   = 101
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Deny"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}
```

I have tried a few different ways of doing this but I can't seem to find the right solution that will allow all `Deny` objects to pass and block any `Allow` objects that are too broad.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get the error message I have defined in my validation block

Comment: Can you post the code of the validation you tried

Comment: Reading your last sentence again: `...the right solution that will allow all Deny objects to pass and block any Allow objects that are too broad.` that sounds more like a filter not actual validation, if we add validation one bad input will fail the plan with an error nothing will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to navigate this with a for:
https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/custom-conditions#for-expressions

```hcl
variable "network_acls" {
  type = map(object({
    direction = string
    access    = string
    prefix    = string
  }))

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for v in var.network_acls : !(v.access == "Allow" && v.prefix == "*")
    ])
    error_message = "Bad value ..."
  }
}
```

my test input file:

```json
{
    "network_acls" : {
        "one": {
          "direction" : "Outbound",
          "access"    : "Allow",
          "prefix"    : "1.1.1.1"
        },
        "two": {
          "direction" : "Inbound",
          "access"    : "Deny",
          "prefix"    : "*"
        }
    }
}
```

Console call:

```txt
terraform plan -var-file="input.tfvars.json"

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

If we change the input on the allow to `*` it errors as it should

```txt
terraform plan -var-file="input.tfvars.json"
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1:
│    1: variable "network_acls" {
│ 
│ Bad value ...
│ 
│ This was checked by the validation rule at main.tf:8,3-13.
|
```